# Detect mobile view called on site

Tags: javascript, css

Is there a way to detect if the site is being viewed in mobile mode? That means the mobile version of the view itself. This should change after the user has called `Request desktop version` from the menu of his browser for example. That's the property I want to handle.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What do you really care about? Why? What do you plan to use the information for?

Comment: Hopefully this previous question answers your question :) [Here!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser)

Comment: Temporary measure in order to advice the user to use the desktop view. You see, my website is just not layed out well yet for mobile and for now, I'd like to just tell that to the user. Something like 'Yeah, I know my site looks ugly on your phone, but you can do your job better, if you switch to desktop view'. That's all, plus I was just curious ^^

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to detect a mobile device in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device-in-jquery)

Comment: Also a possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device-in-jquery

Comment: Also, please do check the tag description of the [website] tag.

Answer (score 0):

> my website is just not layed out well yet for mobile and for now, I'd like to just tell that to the user. Something like 'Yeah, I know my site looks ugly on your phone, but you can do your job better, if you switch to desktop view

The usual way to do this is to use media queries to check the screen size; if it's below a certain value, make the "this layout sucks" button visible.

```
.switchToDesktopButton {display:none}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    /* we're on mobile */
    .switchToDesktopButton {display:block}
}
```